# Work With Char Using If else in C Language

Tags: c, if-statement

Whenever I use `if` Statement to make a decision by comparing a character using `char` and `%d`, then it results in `false` always.

example:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<conio.h>

int main(void) {
  int a, b;
  float r;
  char op;
  printf("Enter 1st num : ");
  scanf("%d", & a);
  printf("Enter 2nd Num : ");
  scanf("%d", & b);
  printf("Enter Operator ( +, - , * , /) : ");
  scanf("%c", & op);
  if (op == '+') {
    r = a + b;
    printf("Ans = %f", r);
    getche();
  } else if (op == '-') {
    r = a - b;
    printf("Ans= %f", r);
  }
  //same as above for remaining 2 functions of * and /
  else
    printf("Error Occurred");
}
```

Comment: Please post a code example

Comment: share some code sample ... that would help resolve where you are wrong

Comment: Show us the code which is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by _**comparing a character using char and %d **_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After typing the second number you press enter, right? `%c` in scanf accepts the first character it finds, so it returns the line break character corresponding to you pressing enter.

An easy fix is to add a space character before `%c`. It makes `scanf` skip any whitespace.

```
scanf(" %c",&op);
```

---

From the scanf documentation (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/):

> **Whitespace character:**
>
> The function will **read and ignore any whitespace characters encountered before the next non-whitespace character** (whitespace characters include spaces, newline and tab characters -- see isspace). A single whitespace in the format string validates **any quantity of whitespace characters** extracted from the stream (including none).

Comment: Please Explain The Reason Behind skipping scanf() statement in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Because %d ignore white-spaces and special characters. White-spaces and special characters are chars. So, %c has to take white-spaces and special characters as inputs.

You can test the output of the code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char p = 'w';
    char l = 'x';
    char t = 't';

    printf("Give one, two or three chars: "); 
    scanf("%c%c%c", &p, &l, &t);              

    printf("p = %c, l = %c, t = %c  \n", p, l, t); // 
    scanf("%c", &t);

    printf("plt = %c%c%c  \n", p,l,t);

    return 0; 
}
```